# How to to cycle through a list of white spaces and distribute the white spaces to another list at specific occurrences?

Tags: python, string, cycle, justify

I would like to align-justify a text. For that, I have used Textwrap in order to fit the maximum amount of words per line with a given width. Now, I need to make sure that every single line has occupied the given width (30) by adding white spaces to fill the line with the following criterium: Large gaps go first, then smaller ones ('Lorem--ipsum--dolor--sit-amet,' (2, 2, 2, 1 spaces)).

```py
import textwrap
def justify(text, width):
    max_words_per_line = textwrap.wrap(text, width, break_long_words=False)
    # I am stuck here, I have tried using the cycle module but I cannot make it work
```

```
max_words_per_line = 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vestibulum sagittis dolor
mauris, at elementum ligula
tempor eget. In quis rhoncus
nunc, at aliquet orci. Fusce
at dolor sit amet felis
suscipit tristique. Nam a
imperdiet tellus. Nulla eu
vestibulum urna. Vivamus
tincidunt suscipit enim, nec
ultrices nisi volutpat ac.
Maecenas sit amet lacinia
arcu, non dictum justo. Donec
sed quam vel risus faucibus
euismod. Suspendisse rhoncus
rhoncus felis at fermentum.
Donec lorem magna, ultricies a
nunc sit amet, blandit
fringilla nunc. In vestibulum
velit ac felis rhoncus
pellentesque. Mauris at tellus
enim. Aliquam eleifend tempus
dapibus. Pellentesque commodo,
nisi sit amet hendrerit
fringilla, ante odio porta
lacus, ut elementum justo
nulla et dolor.
```

I desire:

```
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit amet,
consectetur  adipiscing  elit.
Vestibulum    sagittis   dolor
mauris,  at  elementum  ligula
tempor  eget.  In quis rhoncus
nunc,  at  aliquet orci. Fusce
at   dolor   sit   amet  felis
suscipit   tristique.   Nam  a
imperdiet   tellus.  Nulla  eu
vestibulum    urna.    Vivamus
tincidunt  suscipit  enim, nec
ultrices   nisi  volutpat  ac.
Maecenas   sit   amet  lacinia
arcu,  non dictum justo. Donec
sed  quam  vel  risus faucibus
euismod.  Suspendisse  rhoncus
rhoncus  felis  at  fermentum.
Donec lorem magna, ultricies a
nunc    sit    amet,   blandit
fringilla  nunc. In vestibulum
velit    ac    felis   rhoncus
pellentesque. Mauris at tellus
enim.  Aliquam eleifend tempus
dapibus. Pellentesque commodo,
nisi    sit   amet   hendrerit
fringilla,   ante  odio  porta
lacus,   ut   elementum  justo
nulla et dolor.
```

Comment: Interesting problem. Looks like `textwrap` only exposes methods for _removing_ spaces -- not adding them. Seems like a dynamic programming problem I vaguely recall...

Comment: I found [this solution](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/414870-align-text-string-using-spaces-between-words-to-fi/) which may be of use to you. Sadly looks like `textwrap` doesn't having something built in for you but someone else solved this issue.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161618/text-justification-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vestibulum sagittis dolor
mauris, at elementum ligula
tempor eget. In quis rhoncus
nunc, at aliquet orci. Fusce
at dolor sit amet felis
suscipit tristique. Nam a
imperdiet tellus. Nulla eu
vestibulum urna. Vivamus
tincidunt suscipit enim, nec
ultrices nisi volutpat ac.
Maecenas sit amet lacinia
arcu, non dictum justo. Donec
sed quam vel risus faucibus
euismod. Suspendisse rhoncus
rhoncus felis at fermentum.
Donec lorem magna, ultricies a
nunc sit amet, blandit
fringilla nunc. In vestibulum
velit ac felis rhoncus
pellentesque. Mauris at tellus
enim. Aliquam eleifend tempus
dapibus. Pellentesque commodo,
nisi sit amet hendrerit
fringilla, ante odio porta
lacus, ut elementum justo
nulla et dolor.'''

from itertools import cycle

for line in data.splitlines():
    words = line.split()
    _l = [[' '] for i in range(len(words)-1)]
    spaces = cycle(_l)
    for s, i in zip(spaces, range(30-len(line))):
        s[-1] += ' '
    for w, _l in zip(words, _l):
        print(''.join([w, *_l]), end='')
    print(words[-1])
```

Prints:

```
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit amet,
consectetur  adipiscing  elit.
Vestibulum    sagittis   dolor
mauris,  at  elementum  ligula
tempor  eget.  In quis rhoncus
nunc,  at  aliquet orci. Fusce
at   dolor   sit   amet  felis
suscipit   tristique.   Nam  a
imperdiet   tellus.  Nulla  eu
vestibulum    urna.    Vivamus
tincidunt  suscipit  enim, nec
ultrices   nisi  volutpat  ac.
Maecenas   sit   amet  lacinia
arcu,  non dictum justo. Donec
sed  quam  vel  risus faucibus
euismod.  Suspendisse  rhoncus
rhoncus  felis  at  fermentum.
Donec lorem magna, ultricies a
nunc    sit    amet,   blandit
fringilla  nunc. In vestibulum
velit    ac    felis   rhoncus
pellentesque. Mauris at tellus
enim.  Aliquam eleifend tempus
dapibus. Pellentesque commodo,
nisi    sit   amet   hendrerit
fringilla,   ante  odio  porta
lacus,   ut   elementum  justo
nulla         et        dolor.
```

EDIT: If last line doesn't have to be justified, use this:

```
from itertools import cycle

lines = data.splitlines()

for line in lines[:-1]:
    words = line.split()
    _l = [[' '] for i in range(len(words)-1)]
    spaces = cycle(_l)
    for s, i in zip(spaces, range(30-len(line))):
        s[-1] += ' '
    for w, _l in zip(words, _l):
        print(''.join([w, *_l]), end='')
    print(words[-1])

print(lines[-1])
```

Prints:

```
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit amet,
consectetur  adipiscing  elit.
Vestibulum    sagittis   dolor
mauris,  at  elementum  ligula
tempor  eget.  In quis rhoncus
nunc,  at  aliquet orci. Fusce
at   dolor   sit   amet  felis
suscipit   tristique.   Nam  a
imperdiet   tellus.  Nulla  eu
vestibulum    urna.    Vivamus
tincidunt  suscipit  enim, nec
ultrices   nisi  volutpat  ac.
Maecenas   sit   amet  lacinia
arcu,  non dictum justo. Donec
sed  quam  vel  risus faucibus
euismod.  Suspendisse  rhoncus
rhoncus  felis  at  fermentum.
Donec lorem magna, ultricies a
nunc    sit    amet,   blandit
fringilla  nunc. In vestibulum
velit    ac    felis   rhoncus
pellentesque. Mauris at tellus
enim.  Aliquam eleifend tempus
dapibus. Pellentesque commodo,
nisi    sit   amet   hendrerit
fringilla,   ante  odio  porta
lacus,   ut   elementum  justo
nulla et dolor.
```

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Now also with last line unjustified.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is pretty much the same as Andrej's, but I don't want to throw it away. So here it goes:

```py
from itertools import cycle


def fill_text(text, line_length, skip_last=True):
    lines = text.split('\n')
    for n in range(len(lines)-skip_last):
        words = [w for w in lines[n].split(' ')]  # scrub empty strings
        assert len(words) > 1, f'need at least two words to insert spaces: {words}'

        word_cycle = cycle(range(len(words)-1))  # ignore last word in line
        while sum(len(word) for word in words) < line_length:
            idx = next(word_cycle)
            words[idx] = f'{words[idx]} '
        lines[n] = ''.join(words)

    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

And when called with the example text:

```py
lorem_ipsum = '''\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vestibulum sagittis dolor
mauris, at elementum ligula
tempor eget. In quis rhoncus
nunc, at aliquet orci. Fusce
at dolor sit amet felis
suscipit tristique. Nam a
imperdiet tellus. Nulla eu
vestibulum urna. Vivamus
tincidunt suscipit enim, nec
ultrices nisi volutpat ac.
Maecenas sit amet lacinia
arcu, non dictum justo. Donec
sed quam vel risus faucibus
euismod. Suspendisse rhoncus
rhoncus felis at fermentum.
Donec lorem magna, ultricies a
nunc sit amet, blandit
fringilla nunc. In vestibulum
velit ac felis rhoncus
pellentesque. Mauris at tellus
enim. Aliquam eleifend tempus
dapibus. Pellentesque commodo,
nisi sit amet hendrerit
fringilla, ante odio porta
lacus, ut elementum justo
nulla et dolor.'''
print(fill_text(lorem_ipsum, line_length=30))
```

We get the following:

```
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit amet,
consectetur  adipiscing  elit.
Vestibulum    sagittis   dolor
mauris,  at  elementum  ligula
tempor  eget.  In quis rhoncus
nunc,  at  aliquet orci. Fusce
at   dolor   sit   amet  felis
suscipit   tristique.   Nam  a
imperdiet   tellus.  Nulla  eu
vestibulum    urna.    Vivamus
tincidunt  suscipit  enim, nec
ultrices   nisi  volutpat  ac.
Maecenas   sit   amet  lacinia
arcu,  non dictum justo. Donec
sed  quam  vel  risus faucibus
euismod.  Suspendisse  rhoncus
rhoncus  felis  at  fermentum.
Donec lorem magna, ultricies a
nunc    sit    amet,   blandit
fringilla  nunc. In vestibulum
velit    ac    felis   rhoncus
pellentesque. Mauris at tellus
enim.  Aliquam eleifend tempus
dapibus. Pellentesque commodo,
nisi    sit   amet   hendrerit
fringilla,   ante  odio  porta
lacus,   ut   elementum  justo
nulla et dolor.
```